# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function with custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-custom-hooks

I have a custom hook 'useLogout' that is simple:

```
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useState } from "react";
import { projectAuth } from "../firebase/config";

export const useLogout = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);

  const logout = () => {
    setError("");
    setIsPending(true);
    signOut(projectAuth)
      .then(() => {
        setError("");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
      });
  };

  return { isPending, error, logout };
};
```

I am importing this hook to an element

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { FC, ReactNode } from "react";
import classes from "./NavLink.module.scss";
interface NavbarLinkProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  url: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  clickHandler?: () => void;
}
const NavbarLink: FC<NavbarLinkProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, url, isActive } = { ...props };
  return (
    <li className={`${classes.item} ${isActive ? classes.active : ""}  `}>
      <Link href={url}>
        <a>{children}</a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};
export default NavbarLink;
```

I am using it in the following way:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useLogout } from "../../hooks/useLogout";
import Button from "../Button/button";
import Logo from "./logo";
import classes from "./main-navigation.module.scss";
import NavbarLink from "./NavLink";

const MainNavigation = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { logout } = useLogout();

  return (
    <header className={classes.header}>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>
          <Logo />
        </a>
      </Link>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <NavbarLink
            url="/"
            isActive={router.route === "/logout"}
            clickHandler={() => logout}
          >
            Logout
          </NavbarLink>

          
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default MainNavigation;
```

But I keep getting the folling error:
**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

There are several posts about it but I was not able to find anything specific to my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where does the trace indicate the error is coming from?

Comment: So it turns out that looking at the terminal trace instead of the browser, there are a few additional details that narrowed down the error to one component, which was using an unused function at the bottom after the 'default export'. The function itself was not giving any errors, but once I removed it the app started working again. I am unclear still of why the unused function was causing the app to crash, but this was solved after removing that function.